# Problems with TMinuit

Tags: root-framework

I'm trying to minimize a chi square function in ROOT, this is the FCN code:

```
void myFCNres( int &npar , double * gin , double &f , double * par , int flag ) {

    double chi2 = 0;

    for ( int i = 1 ; i <= datasetNHres->GetSize()-2 ; ++i ) {

        par[7] = Emin + (Emax-Emin)/(2*N_div) + (i-1)*(Emax-Emin)/N_div;
        chi2 += pow( ( integrand->Integral( 1.804 , 8 , par , 1E-15) - datasetNHres->GetBinContent(i)) / datasetNHres->GetBinError(i) ,2);
    }

    chi2 += pow( (par[0] - p[0]) / sig[0] ,2) +
            pow( (par[1] - p[1]) / sig[1] ,2) +
            pow( (par[2] - p[2]) / sig[2] ,2) +
            pow( (par[3] + p[3]) / sig[3] ,2);

    f = chi2;
}
```

The result of running is that none of the parameters has changed, just like my function does not depend on any of them. Do you see problems with FCN logic or I have to look for the bug elsewhere?

Thanks,
Luigi

Comment: Could you also show the part where you use this function with minuit and where you try to get the parameters?

Comment: Solved! But I don't know why those line were needed. Discussion on https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20125&p=86865&sid=562ea587221e09a58c7790da844355b7#p86865